# How to solve problems of performance in the clearFilter() funcion in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, datastore

I am working in a Sencha Touch application and when I use "clearFilter()" I am having a big efforts in terms of performance... For example, when I am writing in the searchfield and following rule specified in the filter (from the second character) I am waiting a second for to write the next character..  What is happening?

Currently my implementation is this:

```
store.clearFilter();
if (queryString && queryString.length > 2) {
      var thisRegEx = new RegExp(queryString, "i");
      store.filterBy(function (record) {
        return (thisRegEx.test(record.get('customerId')) ||
        thisRegEx.test(record.get('customerName')) ||
        thisRegEx.test(record.get('customerAddress')));
      }, this);
    }
```

And it is working but with the problems indicated.

How to solve this of the right way?

Comment: You didn't post any relevant code.

Comment: Code added @EvanTrimboli

Comment: Where's the call to `clearFilter`?

Comment: Previously to the query..

Comment: Did you used any delay for 2-3 seconds to run code after type a character in search field?

Comment: No, I am not adding delay...

Answer (score 2):

The [`clearFilter`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter) has the `suppressEvent` argument:

> `true` to clear silently without firing the `refresh` event.

So try `store.clearFilter(true)`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, how many records are there in the store? The number of records can affect this very much.

To increase performance, you should combine those 3 fields in 1 another field so that you can search in one column with one regexp. 3 regular expression may be expensive for each record. This way, you can also use **filter** method, instead of **filterBy**.

Lastly, i'd prefer using **buffer** option for the listener here to avoid giving hard time to the typer for every single key down. For example:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
listeners: { 
   keyup: {
       buffer: 500, // 500ms
       fn: function(){
           // filter code
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: one question, your approach is with Touch or with ExtJs? because I don´t find buffer or enableKeyEvents properties.. and by the way, in my case i have only 50 records based in one previous filter..

Comment: @inane but you cleared that filter, so you have more than 50 records. Better than clearing the filter would be to just apply a new filter. You can give a filter an `id` property. When you set another filter with the same `id`, it overwrites the old one.

Comment: sorry but I don´t get it... are you telling don´t use "clearFilter()"?

Comment: Sorry, enableKeyEvents removed in touch, but buffer is [there](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener)